# NHibernate is truncating long strings when saving

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, ssms

I am having issues saving very long strings to the database using `NHibernate`. The strings are being truncated to 43,680 characters. The string is a very long `XML` packet that varies in size, but sometimes is very long.

The database data type is `nvarchar(max)` so the limitation is not there.

Can somebody help me understand why `NHibernate` is truncating this, and how I can prevent it?

Here is my mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
  assembly="Application.DataObjects"
  namespace="Company.Application.DataObjects.Transaction.Domain">

  <class name="TransactionDO" table="Transactions">
    <id name="TransactionID">
    </id>
    <property name="Created" />
    <property name="LongXML"  type="StringClob">
      <column name="LongXML" sql-type="nvarchar(max)"/>
    </property>
    <property name="ProcessConstructor" />
    <property name="VeryLongXML" type="StringClob">
      <column name="VeryLongXML" sql-type="nvarchar(max)" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you using? Can try specify the max length for testing to see if works: `<property name="VeryLongXML">
  <column name="VeryLongXML" length="2147483647" /></property>` nvarchar(max), in this case the length of the data can be 2^31-1 bytes

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that. The version is 3.2. I have tried to specify the string length of 100000. and it still returned the same number of characters.

Comment: How are you verifying the strings are limited to 43,680 characters? There's a known bug in `Sql Server Management Studio 2008` that only show's strings at this limit in the grid, workarounds known.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you for that. I didn't think about Management Studio being the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments in the OP's question, the issue was in `SSMS` displaying the data.

There is a known bug in `Sql Server Management Studio 2008` [that you cannot paste more than 43679 characters from a column in Grid Mode.](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/499608/ssms-can-not-paste-more-than-43679-characters-from-a-column-in-grid-mode)

[Options (Query Results/SQL Server/Results to Grid Page) version SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190078%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> The maximum characters retrieved in Grid Mode for non XML data should be 65535 characters.

Severals ways have been discussed to display the `XML` through `SSMS`:

- Set Maximum Characters Retrieved to `XML` data and set the limit to **Unlimited**.

  Try casting the result to `XML`, i.e. `cast(COLUMN_NAME as XML)`
- Breaking output of column to multiple rows
- Copy-paste column to another program
- Third party tooling (ssmsboost)

Alternatively, these discussions might be useful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5508193/368552, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2760023/368552

Answer (score 1):

You can add length property and set it to max length ("2147483647") to ensure full storage of xml string; like

```
<property name="VeryLongXML" type="StringClob" length="2147483647">
```