# How to get complete data from SQL management studio for ntext column?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, ssms, ntext

I am using SQL server 2005. In one of the tables, I have a column "xmldefinition" which is of ntext type. Now the data in this column is very huge and contains whole xml text.

eg:- `<root><something1>....</something1></root>`

I want to get the whole string from management studio and copy it outside in a xml file just to go through the whole xml manually. But when I query for this column and I copy and paste the data into another file, the contents are broken in middle and it is not complete.

eg:- `<root><something1>........<somechar`

I believe this will copy only some 8196 characters from xml data in column. So my question is, how do I get the complete data for this column manually. I can however write a C# code to read that column, but I want to do this manually in management studio. Any idea please.

Comment: NTEXT is deprecated - don't use it anymore. If you have XML data - why not use the `XML` datatype in the first place?? That would be the most optimized storage for XML.... if you can't - then at least switch to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead of NTEXT...... with that, getting the full string is easy

Comment: @marc_s - yes, you are right. But this is some kind of legacy system and we are working on a framework which adds columns as ntext only for now. That framework is from a third party vendor. So currently we have to go with ntext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not convert the data from NText to XML in your select statement?  Then you get the option of opening up the XML in a separate window within SSMS.

Comment: Absolutely works. Thanks. The surprising part is, I was not aware of this xml datatype. A simple cast works for me now... Cool.

Answer (score 5):

The export technique shown in [SQL Server truncation and 8192 limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952247/sql-server-truncation-and-8192-limitation) worked for me.  In summary it says:

You can export the data to a flat file which will not be truncated. To do this:

- Right click the Database
- Click Tasks -> Export Data
- Select your Data Source (defaults should be fine)
- Choose "Flat File Destination" for the Destination type.
- Pick a file name for the output.
- On the "Specify Table Copy or Query", choose "Write a query to specify the data to transfer"
- Paste in your query

Remaining steps should be self explanatory. This will output the file to text and you can open it in your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 3):

The only way of exceeding this limit in general is via XML. For long varchar columns I normally use something like the following (the processing instruction trick avoids `<` being changed to `&lt;` etc.)

```
select object_definition(object_id('sysdatabases')) 
 as [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH
```

Of course in your case the data is already XML so a simple cast should work!

Comment: Thanks for additional info too. Yes, for me a simple cast to xml works now. Good to know, this was something new to me.