# TSQL get definition for loooong sp

Tags: sql-server-2012

I successfully used this code but now I'm dealing with huge sp and I see that results truncated, probably limited to some 5K limit??
How I can store it all?

Thanks much

```
SELECT name, OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE name LIKE 'p_my_big_sp_2000lines%'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server truncation and 8192 limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952247/sql-server-truncation-and-8192-limitation)

Comment: Try this 
`SELECT    O.Name as ProcName 
        ,M.Definition as CreateScript
     FROM sys.sql_modules as M INNER JOIN sys.objects as O 
ON M.object_id = O.object_id 
WHERE O.type = 'P' `