# How to output XmlData column in full in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table column that is xmldata type and stores very long XML texts. When I use SELECT to output the column to TEXT or FILE, it is truncated. How can I output full content?

Comment: Do you really _need_ to see the full content?  If not, you could try using an XPath expression to obtain the portion of the XML you need, q.v. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344553/how-can-i-query-a-value-in-sql-server-xml-column).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, I need full content.

Comment: Have you checked the solution by Martin Smith on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952247/sql-server-truncation-and-8192-limitation)