# write complete JSON to file system in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

I am using:

```
FOR JSON PATH
```

to transform my sql result set into JSON this works fine. How can I write the complete text to the file system (I am using SSMS and chose query -> results to -> results to file)? Currently, data is cutoff. I guess there is some property I can set in sql server management studio? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean there is a "cutoff"? Are you copy and pasting it from SSMS, where there is a limit to the about of characters displayed in a cell (about 65,000~ if you change the default setting)? If you want to export the data, you should be looking at an ETL process, or `bcp`, `sqlcmd` or something.

Comment: cutoff as of when I write results to file system rather than grid. I am not copying from grid ...

Comment: So how are you writing them to the file system? Explain that in your question. We can't explain why the data is being "cut off" if you don't tell us what it is you're doing,

Comment: chose query -> results to -> results to file - made this clearer mind you I thought that's obvious as I purely use SSMS

Comment: *"mind you I thought that's obvious as I purely use SSMS"* Considering that I described 1 alternative you're not using, and I can think of a couple of others, no it wasn't clear. But actually, my point stands, if you want to export the data you need to use something else. SSMS is a management tool, not an ETL tool. Export to File will truncate individual values just like results to Grid do.

Comment: this is just a one of export and ssms should work for this. I remember that I had to adjust something in the properties to export large texts in columns. I would assume there is a similar for this use case.

Comment: There is the setting in `Options`->`Tools`->`Query Results`->`SQL Server`->`Results to Grid`->`Non XML Data` to change the total length returned (maximum value being 65535), but if you need much larger values, then what I state in the comment is still true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are asking below

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5508193/2118383)

I also use XML but [a slightly different method](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/499618/ssms-allow-large-text-to-be-displayed-in-as-a-link) that gets around most of the issues with XML entitisation.

```
declare @VeryLongText nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT top 100 @VeryLongText = @VeryLongText + '

' + OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) 
FROM sys.all_objects 
WHERE type='P' and is_ms_shipped=1

SELECT LEN(@VeryLongText)

SELECT @VeryLongText AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('')

PRINT @VeryLongText /*WILL be truncated*/
```

Make sure that the "XML data" limit in SSMS is set sufficiently high!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This did the job. Thanks! I knew there was some property.