# SQL Query with a WHERE clause containing binary data

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, binary-data

I have a table with rows containing binary data as seen below. (I would copy and paste but it is huge)

[image: Collection of rows containing binary data]

When I take the data from the first row and substitute it for the variable 'x' in the below query I receive no results despite it clearly existing in that table.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE Logo = x
```

I created a mock table to test this type of query which contains these two values;

0x123456
0x7890

When I execute the following query I am greeted with the correct result.

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE Column = 0x123456
```

Comment: What do you mean by "insert it into 'x'"

Comment: @Magnus say I have the value 0x12345 in the row, I want to take this value and search the table for it. i.e

SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE Logo = 0x12345

Comment: So your mock table works but not the real?

Comment: @Magnus Yes that is correct.

Comment: What is your engine? SQL Server, MySQL or something else?

Comment: You binary data looks large, are you searching for the complete value?

Comment: @igg SQL Server, 2016 to be specific.

Comment: @Magnus Yes I am looking for a complete value.

Comment: What is the exact query that does not work? Also can you confirm the datatype of the table column.

Comment: Where are you running the query? If it's via Management Studio then you may be running into the max character limit of 8192. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952247/sql-server-truncation-and-8192-limitation)

Comment: @Magnus I'm afraid I cannot write the exact query. But it contains a varbinary value that is 65,535 characters long which leads me onto strickt01 's question. See next comment.

Comment: @strickt01 I followed the steps in this to export but I am greeted with this error

The data type for "Destination - temp_txt.Inputs[Flat File Destination Input].Columns[Logo]" is DT_IMAGE, which is not supported. Use DT_TEXT or DT_NTEXT instead and convert the data from, or to, DT_IMAGE using the data conversion component.

This is a technically a separate question now.

Comment: You need to set the data type for the column to something other than DT_IMAGE to export it to a flat file. You can do this in the expot wizard. Failing that, try the answer on the SO question from Luke Sampson re. saving the results to a CSV file.

Comment: Why do you need to query on a binary value in the first place. It seems very odd. Is this part of an application or a one time query?

Comment: @Magnus we need to update specific rows that contain the same data. The database setup produces a lot of redundant data unfortunately :(

Comment: You could create a hash of the binary data and store that and than a hash of the data you want to find. And than compare the hashes instead of the binary data.